# preg_replace: how to consider whole array of patterns before replacing?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using `preg_replace` to match and replace improperly encoded UTF-8 characters with their proper characters. I've created a "old" array containing the wrong characters, and a corresponding "new" array with the replacements. Here is a snippet of each array:

```
$old = array(
  '/â€/',
  '/â€™/',
);
$new = array(
  '†',
  '’',
);
```

(**Note**: If you're curious about why I'm doing this, [read more here](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html))

A sample string that may contain the wrong data could be:

`The programmerâ€™s becoming very frustrated`

Which should become:

`The programmer's becoming very frustrated`

I'm using this function:

`$result = preg_replace($old, $new, $str);`

But the subject is actually becoming:

`The programmer†™s becoming very frustrated`

It's clear that PHP is doing what I call a non-greedy match on the subject (not the correct term to use here, I know). `preg_replace` is executing the replacement on the first pair in the old/new array without considering if there may a different pattern in the pattern array that is more appropriate. If I reverse the order of the replacement pair, then it works as expected.

My question is: Is there an approach that will allow `preg_replace` to consider all elements of the pattern array before executing a replacement, or is my only option to re-order the arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any option like that. However, you could use an associative array to store your replacements and sort it using [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort) and [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen), so larger matches would come first and you wouldn't need to manage your array order manually.

Then you can use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) and [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) to act just like your separated `$old` and `$new` arrays.

```
$replacements = array(
    '†' => '/â€/',
    '’' => '/â€™/',
);

// sorts the replacements array by value string length keeping the indexes intact
uasort($replacements, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});

$str = 'The programmerâ€™s becoming very frustrated';
$result = preg_replace(array_values($replacements), array_keys($replacements), $str);
```

**EDIT:** As @CasimiretHippolyte pointed out, using `array_values` is not necessary on the first parameter of the `preg_replace` function in this case. It would only return a copy from `$replacements` with numerical indexes but the order would be the same. Unless you need an array with identical structure to `$old` from your question, you do not need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Order the arrays `$old`  and `$new` in such way that the longest regex becomes first:

```
$old = array(
  '/â€™/',
  '/â€/',
);
$new = array(
  '’',
  '†',
);
$str = 'The programmerâ€™s becoming very frustrated';
$result = preg_replace($old, $new, $str);
echo $result,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
The programmer’s becoming very frustrated
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do this only using `preg_replace`. However you can easily do this sorting your array beforehand:

```
$replacements = array_combine($old, $new);
krsort($replacements);
$result = preg_repalce( array_keys($replacements), array_values($replacements), $string);
```